# Debugging .Cells(i - 3, "A").Formula = "=Sheet2!A" & i & ""

Tags: vba, excel

non-professional in VBA trying to debug my code. Whoever made this code is gone for good.
This Sub looks like this:

```
Sub UpdateFormulaCUI()
Dim i As Integer
i = 6
With Sheets("CUI")

    Do Until Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, "A") = ""


        .Cells(i - 3, "A").Formula = "=Sheet2!A" & i & ""
        .Cells(i - 3, "B").Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A" & i - 3 & ",Purchases!A:P,7,FALSE),"""")"
        .Cells(i - 3, "D").Formula = "=GETPIVOTDATA(""Sum of Inventory"",Sheet2!$A$3,""Inventory" & Chr(10) & "Number"",A" & i - 3 & ")"
        .Cells(i - 3, "E").Formula = "=GETPIVOTDATA(""Average of Cost $"",Sheet2!$A$3,""Inventory" & Chr(10) & "Number"",A" & i - 3 & ")"
        .Cells(i - 3, "F").Formula = "=D" & i - 3 & "*E" & i - 3 & ""

    i = i + 1
    Loop
End With
i = 6
With Sheets("CUI")

    Do Until Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, "A") = ""


        .Cells(i - 3, "A") = .Cells(i - 3, "A")
        .Cells(i - 3, "B") = .Cells(i - 3, "B")
        .Cells(i - 3, "D") = .Cells(i - 3, "D")
        .Cells(i - 3, "E") = .Cells(i - 3, "E")
        .Cells(i - 3, "F") = .Cells(i - 3, "F")

    i = i + 1
    Loop

End With

End Sub
```

The line in subject of this post gets stopped. With my limited knowledge of VBA I can't understand what `"=Sheet2!A" & i & ""` stands for.
Please help!

Comment: can you please explain better what is the question? what do you want people to answer about?

Comment: the code is using i as a variable to add (1) to every time it loops, so that the references in the formula change with the loop.  Ai could be A1, A2, A3, A4 depending on the value of i.  The & is the way for VB to note that you are going to add more to what was in the quotes already. 'str = "this" ------- "Hope " & str & " helps"

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
.Cells(i - 3, "A").Formula = "=Sheet2!A" & i & ""
```

states that the *formula* in a particular cell is being set to a certain string. The variable 'i' is a number that changes over the loop.  For example, when i=5, you've essentially got:

```
.Cells(2, "A").Formula = "=Sheet2!A5"
```

If you step through the macro and stop it, you will find that the cell you are referencing has a formula now in it, and it should be =Sheet2!A5

If the sheet doesn't exist, that might cause your error.

When this stops, does it give a *particular* error?

Adding information here - the reference above refers to the *name* of the sheet, not the list you see in the Macro editor.

So, if you Sheet11(Sheet2), that's the one you are referencing.  If you see Sheet2(Sales), the name of that sheet is 'Sales' - that's what you would use in the formula.

Comment: This answers my question. can you add the link to the library where this type of reference to cell is described? I mean "& i &"

Comment: Now, here is the link to the screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jy3jki3qf644epk/Screenshot%202014-12-04%2012.49.28.png?dl=0 so in left panel you see Sheet11(Sheet2) and then further down Sheet2(Sales). So now this reference we had before refers to which one? Thanks

Comment: clic - See the additional information in the answer.

Comment: Got it. Run-time error 1004 see https://www.dropbox.com/s/1lbbi1crm2pshan/Screenshot%202014-12-04%2014.05.45.png?dl=0 Unprotecting sheet doesn't help. The error message comes back

Comment: Make a copy of the spreadsheet, and start only with that spreadsheet.   I'd also step through the macro, one command at a time.

Comment: The issue was resolved by inserting Unprotect and Protect commands at the beginning and end of sub